How did the Sicilian vespers revolution against the Angevins lead to the rise of the Sicilian mafia?
I was recently reading an article on the origins of the Mafia and read that the revolution of the Sicilian vespers, and the underground movement was essentially viewed as the birth of the organization that would come to be known as the mafia, though it isn't really clear how that happened, and was wondering if there were any additional information that could help clear this up?

The Wikipedia page on the subject flat out states that's an urban myth. However, its a myth with an interesting history. I could see a case for making an answer of it...
